# how to validate a property according to another property in DataAnnotation

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, data-annotations

Consider I have a these two properties:

```
public class Test
{
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please Enetr Age")]
    public System.Int32 Age { get; set; }
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Choose an option")]
    public System.Boolean IsOld { get; set; }
}
```

When the user enters for example 15 for `Age` and choose "`Yes`" for `IsOld`, I return an exception that correct `Age` or `IsOld`. I've used `CustomValidation` for it, but because my my validation must be static I can't access to other properties. How can I do this by a `DataAnnotation`?

Comment: As far as i see, it will throw an exception if any of those values is not submitted. What else you want ?? Actually it's not very understanding what you are looking for

Comment: I say if all of them enetred???use enter 15 for Age and choose IsOld.

Comment: Do you mean to say if someone enter a value in your `Age` property, then the `IsOld` is set to true by itself ??

Comment: Are you a programmer?First:it is a typical example any may does not exist in real world.second:User entered both the Age and IsOld

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can add data annotations (Custom Validator) to the class itself. In the isValid method of your validation attribute you should then be able to cast the object and test the values that need to be fulfilled.

Example:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            // setup test object
            Test t = new Test() { Age = 16, IsOld = true };
            // store validation results
            Collection<ValidationResult> validationResults = new Collection<ValidationResult>();
            // run validation
            if (Validator.TryValidateObject(t, new ValidationContext(t, null, null), validationResults, true))
            {
                // validation passed
                Console.WriteLine("All items passed validation");
            }
            else
            {
                // validation failed
                foreach (var item in validationResults)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(item.ErrorMessage);
                }
            }
            Console.ReadKey(true);
        }
    }

    [TestValidation(ErrorMessage = "Test object is not valid")]
    public class Test
    {
        public int Age { get; set; }
        public bool IsOld { get; set; }
    }

    public class TestValidation : ValidationAttribute
    {
        public override bool IsValid(object value)
        {
            bool isValid = false;
            Test testVal = value as Test;
            if (testVal != null)
            {
                // conditional logic here
                if ((testVal.Age >= 21 && testVal.IsOld) || (testVal.Age < 21 && !testVal.IsOld))
                {
                    // condition passed
                    isValid = true;
                }
            }
            return isValid;
        }
    }
}
```