# Custom Validation For Required fields

Tags: validation, c#-4.0, model-view-controller, asp.net-web-api, data-annotations

Hi I would want to have validations something of this sort

```
[RequiredCustom(ActionType=(int)Action.Update, ActionType=(int)Action.Delete)]
public string NotesID { get; set; }

[Required]
[RegularExpression("1|2|3|4")]
public int ActionType { get; set; }
```

I would want to validate this NotesID only when Updation and Deletion is taking place. I don't need any javascript code for unobtrusive and all. I just want server side validation.

Please don't suggest use of separate models I can't do that. Something similar solution will also do.

Let me know if this requires more clarification, Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

If you are ok with placing the validation data annotations on the class itself, you could do something like the answer to this post (by Gary.S) suggests.

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8283968/how-to-validate-a-property-according-to-another-property-in-dataannotation)

In essense, just create a new custom validation attribute and since its an attribute at class level, you will have access to the object itself and hence access to other properties.

You custom attribute should look something like this (Assuming your class name is 'Notes')

```
public class RequiredCustom: ValidationAttribute
    {
        List<int> actions;
        public RequiredCustom(int[] actions)
        {
            this.actions = new List<int>();
            this.actions.AddRange(actions);
        }

        public override bool IsValid(object value)
        {
            bool isValid = true;
            Notes testVal = value as Notes;
            if(this.actions.Contains((int)testVal.Action))
            {
                if(string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(testVal.NotesID))
                {
                   isValid = false;
                }
            }
            return isValid;
        }
    }
```

Then, add the validation attribute on the class and send the array of enums you want to test for. This way it will be dynamic enough to send other later. In this case, I am sending an ARRAY of Update and Delete enums since you have a special case for these two.

```
[RequiredCustom(new int[] {(int)Action.Update, (int)Action.Delete)}]
public class Notes
{
   public string NotesID { get; set; }

   [Required]
   [RegularExpression("1|2|3|4")]
   public int ActionType { get; set; }
}
```

Remember, this will work only if you set the attribute on the class, not on the NotesId property.

Comment: I want to use it like 
[RequiredCustom(ActionType=(int)Action.Update, ActionType=(int)Action.Delete)]
Can you be more specific, I am not really very clear with your solution. Will object contain my ActionType attribute??

Comment: Ajay, I updated the answer to be a little more clear. Just remember like I said initially, this will work if you use the attribute on the class (sine your validation is dependent on another property of the class) and not on the NotedID property itself. This might not be the answer you were expecting if you want to add some validation messages on the property, etc, but should give you an idea. Let me know if you have any questions.

Comment: Hi @Krishna It doesn't resolve my issue, Since I've multiple properties for this operation